# How to use Redux selector (Reselect) with button to query Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to learn Redux and Redux selectors. My React application has list group where each list group button represents a category. It also displays all items from redux store. When the user clicks on a category, there should be displayed only items that belong to clicked category.
I have constructed the selector that filters items that belong to a 'Strategy' category, and it looks like this:

```
const categorySelector = createSelector(
    allBoardgames,
    data => data.filter(d => d.value.category.some(cat => cat === 'Strategy'))
);
```

I mapped state to props like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
    results: categorySelector(state)
    };
}
```

My list group is rendering like this:

```
renderCategories() {
    return this.state.categories.map(category => {
      return (
        <ListGroupItem
          tag='button'
          action
          key={category.key}
          //onClick={() => this.props.fetchCategoryItems(category.value)}
        >
          {category.value}
        </ListGroupItem>
      );
    });
}
```

Now that onClick event should call selector and update redux state or component state so that application only displays items that belong to clicked category. Whats the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: where is the clicked category stored and how are you updating it

Comment: All categories are mapped from component state, and items are stored in redux store. I want to filter the store by clicking on a category and then display only the filtered items

Comment: There is only one list that shows items or each category shows it's own list ? How many lists of items are shown in parallel ?